# How can I pass a templated fixed string to the overload of a constructor of another class

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm having issues when trying to pass an already initialized string of chars which literally doesn't take the overload correctly:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>

    class A {
        char m_m[N];
        public:
            A(char const (&p)[N]) {
                // Copy p to m_m
                std::ranges::copy(p, m_m);
            }
    };

template <std::size_t N>
    class B {
        public: B(A<N> a) {
            // Perform some operation on 'a'
        }
    };

int main() {
    auto k = B("test");
}
```

I'm currently getting:

```
prog.cc:26:22: error: no matching function for call to 'B(const char [5])'
prog.cc:20:5: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int N> B(A<N>)-> B<N>'
20 |     B(A<N> a) {
```

Comment: Do you realize that it’s CTAD that’s failing here (such that the question is how to fix _that_)?

Comment: @DavisHerring actually yes I guess, isn't matching the overload and I'm not sure why

Comment: What kind of an example does your C++ textbook shows of `std::copy`? How many parameters to this function does your C++ textbook say you must provide, and what should they be? If your textbook says you need to provide only two parameters, like this, you need a new textbook.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry, it was using 'std::ranges::copy', I edited it. but It needs to be compile time evalutated.

Comment: @Nickolov CTAD happens before overload resolution.  The compiler needs to figure out what `N` should be before it even starts considering possible conversions.  Add a deduction guide for `const char (&)[N]` or explicitly convert the parameter to an `A`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek apparently compiles when I pass the length manually `auto k = B<5>("test");`, well, I guess I need to figure out how I can evaluate the length automatically.

Comment: well, I workaround'd with `B(char const(&p)[N]) : m_m2(A<N>(p))` making a temporary memeber, but I'm open to new ideas.

Comment: You don't need a temporary member. `B(char const (&p)[N]) : B(A<N>(p)){}`

Answer (score 3):

in your code [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) is failing as the compiler needs to deduce the type of `B<N>` to instantiate the type `A<N>`, and it can't deduce `B<N>` from the input char array.

to get CTAD to work you could provide a deduction guide as follows

```
// deduce N at call site, B<N> is deduced, so A<N> is instantiated
template<std::size_t N>
B(char const (&)[N]) -> B<N>;
```

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <array>

template <std::size_t N>

    class A {
        char m_m[N];
        public:
            A(char const (&p)[N]) {
                // Copy p to m_m
                std::ranges::copy(p, m_m);
            }
    };

template <std::size_t N>
    class B {
        public: B(A<N> a) {
            // Perform some operation on 'a'
        }
    };

// deduce N for input char const array
template<std::size_t N>
B(char const (&)[N]) -> B<N>;

int main() {
    auto k = B("test");
}
```